# How to catch C headers being included outside "extern "C" {}"?

Tags: c++

When including C headers in C++ code it's necessary to put them within "extern "C" {}" to avoid name mangling. Failling to do so gives errors which are not easily connected to the original mistake.

Is there a good solution to this? E.g. a way to catch these errors earlier or get more descriptive error messages?

Comment: Would wrapper headers be an option? I.e. for each C header a C++ header which includes them within an `extern`. Then including them is the interface, remembering to do the `extern` is not needed.

Comment: If the library was designed with C++ in mind, then it will already contain the necessary `extern "C"` wrapper in its header, so that you don't need to add it yourself. It it doesn't, then there isn't really a way to differentiate a C from a C++ header. How would a compiler/tool be able to tell which includes to warn about and which not?

Comment: How would you know whether `int foo(int);` is a C or C++ declaration? You can't determine it from the declaration, you'd need to know where that function is defined and how that Translation Unit was compiled. And figuring out things across TU's is necessarily done at link time - it cannot be earlier.

Comment: Why dos the solution of errors from the linker not suffice for you? The application cannot be built... Common linkers clearly state the problem.

Comment: Putting `#include` directives inside an `extern "C" { ... }` block **might** work, but it's a sledgehammer, and an inaccurate one. For example, `int f(void *class);` is legal C but not legal C++; `extern "C"` doesn't change that.